# Wordpress reset password link redirecting to a 404 page

Tags: wordpress, passwords, http-status-code-404, change-password

The title says itself, I've tried disabling plugins, switching themes, all result in an error.
I downloaded frontend password reset, the error still occurred.

1. The user enters username/email to receive reset password link
2. The user receives the link
3. The user clicks the link
4. The user is then redirected to a 404 "Page not found"

Please help!

Comment: have you refreshed permalinks?

Comment: And cleared the cache (*all* caches - the browser, the server, any WP plugin caches, etc)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't appear to be programming-related. This site is for programming-specific questions. Questions about WordPress administration, server configuration, etc. are off topic and are more suited to the [dedicated WordPress Development Stack Exchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com).  However please review their help section first before posting to make sure your question meets their guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Goto Settings > General > Permalinks.
2. Check that you have values in the reset password field.
3. Click Save.

Even if you dont change anything, click save to flush your permalinks. Try your reset process again and see if they helps.

**Note:** Create a backup of your wordpress site before making any changes incase any changes break links in your site.

Comment: What do you mean? There is no "reset password field" field on the permalinks page.